# ToC, LoF, LoT, Acronyms consistent layout

Tags: table-of-contents, acro

I am writing my thesis and I want the elements of: ToC, LoF, LoT, Acronyms, and Symbols to have the same layout. For the Acronyms and Symbols I want to use the `acro` package that gives me the flexibility to define diferent list types.

I may define a list to use in the `acro` that I may set the distance between lines and other things. But I have no idea how to do that for the ToC, LoF, LoT. Also I may have the chance to use `leaders` (dots) or avoid them but have the page numbers.

My MWE is below:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}% provides \makefirstuc
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{acronyms}{description}{1}
\setlist[acronyms]{labelwidth = 4em, leftmargin = 4.5em, noitemsep, itemindent = 0pt}
\acsetup{%
    index = false,
    list-long-format = \makefirstuc,
    list-type = acronyms,
    hyperref = true,
    extra-style = comma,
    page-ref = comma,
    }

\DeclareAcronym{TV}
{%
    short={TV},
    long={Television},
    short-plural={},
    long-plural={},
    class={general},
    short-format=\scshape,
    index={TV}
}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures
\printacronyms[heading=chapter*]

\chapter{AAAA}

\section{CCC}


\ac{TV}

\chapter{AAAA}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Figure test}
\label{fig:test}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
\caption{Table test}
\label{tab:test}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This answer given by me could help you. Check it out.
[For consistent layout][1].


  [1]: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255582/formatting-the-table-of-contents-and-the-list-of-tables/255907#255907

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for. It is missing the acro layout for acronyms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`acro` now (since 2015/09/05) has a list-style `toc` and a list-style `lof`. Using your example with the `book` class and the following `acro` setup:

```
\acsetup{
  list-long-format = \makefirstuc ,
  list-style = lof ,
  list-heading = chapter* ,
  extra-style = comma
}
```

The list of figures:

[image]

and the list of acronyms:

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}% provides \makefirstuc

\acsetup{
  index = false,
  list-long-format = \makefirstuc ,
  list-style = lof ,
  list-heading = chapter* ,
  extra-style = comma
}

\DeclareAcronym{TV}{
  short = TV ,
  long = Television ,
  short-plural = ,
  long-plural = ,
  class = general ,
  short-format = \scshape ,
  index = TV
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures
\printacronyms

\chapter{AAAA}
\section{CCC}

\ac{TV}

\chapter{AAAA}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Figure test}
\label{fig:test}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
\caption{Table test}
\label{tab:test}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

A consistent interface for ToC, LoF, LoT and LoA:

```
\documentclass[10pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}  % this package styles ToC, LoT and LoF (this 
% package is necessary)
\usepackage{longtable}        % to use longtable in acro (necessary package)
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}      % T1 encoding
\usepackage{lmodern}          % using Latin Modern font

%=========     Customizing ToC

% increasing right margin which makes width available for titles smaller
% hence grater the value smaller the title width
\cftsetrmarg{3cm}

% Removing leaders from all ToC, LoF and LoT to make these consistent with
% List of Acronyms because it doesn't support such design

\renewcommand{\cftpartdotsep}{\cftnodots}
\renewcommand{\cftchapdotsep}{\cftnodots} % if a class article or similar to
% article is used remove this command or it will produce an error
\renewcommand{\cftsecdotsep}{\cftnodots}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecdotsep}{\cftnodots}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecdotsep}{\cftnodots}
\renewcommand{\cftparadotsep}{\cftnodots}
\renewcommand{\cftsubparadotsep}{\cftnodots}
\renewcommand{\cftfigdotsep}{\cftnodots}
%\renewcommand{\cftsubfigdotsep}{\cftnodots} % if sub figures are used then
% uncomment this command
\renewcommand{\cfttabdotsep}{\cftnodots}
%\renewcommand{\cftsubtabdotsep}{\cftnodots} % if sub tables are used then
% uncomment this command


\usepackage[messages=silent,only-used=true,sort=false]{acro} % To use acronyms

\DeclareAcronym{cd}{
  short         = CD,
  long          = Compact Disc
}
\DeclareAcronym{ny}{
short = NY ,
short-plural = ,
long = New York ,
long-plural =
}

\DeclareAcronym{sw}{
short = SW ,
long = Sammelwerk ,
long-plural = e
}
\DeclareAcronym{MP}{
short = MP ,
long = Member of Parliament ,
long-plural-form = Members of Parliament
}

\DeclareAcronym{unesco}{
  short = UNESCO,
  long = {United Nations Educational, Scientific and Cultural Organization}
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\listoffigures
\clearpage

\listoftables
\clearpage

\acsetup{
  page-ref=plain,
  page-name={\@ },
  pages-name={\@\,},      
  list-name={List of Acronyms},   % List name
  list-heading=chapter*,          % formatting of heading
  list-type=table,                % list-style, this enables the following option
  list-style=extra-longtable-rev, % style of list used don't change 
  list-table-width=0.7\linewidth  % width of second + third column in list
}
\printacronyms
\clearpage

\part{Part One}
\chapter{A very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long chapter title}

\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subection A}

\subsection{Subection B}
\subsection{Subection C}

\begin{figure*}[h!]
\caption{Figure caption 1}
\end{figure*}


\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subection A}
\subsection{Subection B}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\caption{Figure caption}
\end{figure}

\subsection{Subection C}

\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subection A}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\caption{Figure caption}
\end{figure}

\subsection{Subection B}
\subsection{Subection C}
\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{Table Caption}
\end{table}

\ac{cd}

\ac{sw}

\ac{ny}

\ac{MP}

\ac{unesco}
\clearpage

\ac{cd}

\ac{sw}

\ac{ny}

\ac{MP}

\ac{unesco}

\clearpage
\ac{cd}

\ac{sw}

\ac{ny}

\ac{MP}

\ac{unesco}
\clearpage
\ac{cd}

\ac{sw}

\ac{ny}

\ac{MP}

\ac{unesco}
\clearpage
\ac{cd}

\ac{sw}

\ac{ny}

\ac{MP}

\ac{unesco}


\part{Appendix}
% Use starred version of chapters, section etc which do not appear in table of contents

\chapter*{A}
\chapter*{B}

\part{Index}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I *knew* your mail was no coincidence! :) (I will test your code later before I vote)

Comment: There is two problems with your solution: 1) I cannot use `dotfill`, which in fact may not be a problem depending on the desired style; 2) I cannot accurately set the table width for the acronyms table. If you enable `showframe` in `geometry` package, you will notice the difference.

Comment: Can you please be more specific about problems, because (1) there are no dots used in ToC or anywhere else and (2) table width for acronyms is within the frame when enabling `showframe` in `geometry`, it is just like other tables.